# dynamoDB update_item method - key element does not match schema error just doesnt go. Tried everything

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have tried all methods mentioned in many different docs of aws dynamoDB.
[like this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item) and [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.update_item).

Also referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34447304/example-of-update-item-in-dynamodb-boto3).

But it just doesn't seem to work.

I have this entry in dynamoDB:

```
dict1={
    'token':1234567890,
    'name':'bigCompany',
    'nestedDict':{
        'a':3810,
        'b':3815,
        'c':3805,
        'd':3811
        },
    'High1':3815,
    'Low1':3805
}
```

And i'm using this code to update an attribute:

```
updater = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'token': '1234567890',
        'name':'bigCompany'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#LM':'Low1'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':nlm': {
            'N':'3802'
            }
    },
    ReturnValues='UPDATED_OLD',
    UpdateExpression='SET #LM = :nlm',
)
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updating1.py", line 89, in <module>
    UpdateExpression='SET #LM = :nlm',
  File ".local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File ".local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File ".local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File ".local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema
```

What am i missing here.

Comment: just a quick guess, but do you need quotes around the `nlm` value?  Should it read `'N':3802` (no quotes around the number?)

Comment: Is `table` a DynamoDB resource or a DynamoDB client? Presume the former. With the resource-level API, you don't provide numeric values as strings and you don't have to indicate `{ 'N': 'value' }` so use `'token': 1234567890` in the key and `':nlm': 3802` in the ExpressionAttributeValues.

Comment: @SethGeoghegan i have tried both ways but the error sustains

Comment: @jarmod i took a hint from your pointer about resource and client. I had initialized the object as a resource but was referring to documentation for a client. After following steps for client, i was finally able to update.. However, it seems i have to stick to {'N':'value'} {'S':'Value'} type syntax for clients.. whereas in resource it seems it's not required.. i will check that as well..... Many thanks for the pointer..

Comment: @jarmod i referred to [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html) documentation about dynamodb resource, and followed all steps but it gives out the same error as in my question..

Comment: UPDATE: i was able to update using the link mentioned in the above comment... thanks all for your help

Comment: pl check my answer.. it will make it clear

Comment: The fix I gave you earlier worked correctly. I just tested it. And I explained the difference between the two APIs (client and resource) which you had mixed up.

Comment: yes, as i mentioned in my earlier comment, i had initialized the boto3 object as a resource but was referring to documentation of client. I got that hint from your comment.

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear here somehow, but I'm glad the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the pointers provided by good people in comments, i was able to resolve this so updating both methods.

The issue originally was, i had initiated a boto3 object as a resource using boto3.resource(), however was referring to aws documentation of boto3.client().

If you're using a resource, the update method is easier:
[this is documentation link for boto3 resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html)

```
changer = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'token': '1234567890',
        'name':'bigCompany'
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET LM = :val1',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val1': 3802
    }
)
```

However, if you're using a client, then you'll have to change the syntax:
[this is the documentation link for boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item)

```
changer = client.update_item(
    Key={
        'token': {
            'N':'1234567890',
            },
        'company': {
            'S':'bigCompany'
            },
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#LM':'val1'},
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val1': {
            'N':'3802',
        },
    },
    ReturnValues='UPDATED_OLD',
    UpdateExpression='SET #LM = :val1',
    TableName='myTable'
)
```

Hope no one get's confused now.

Comment: You should indicate `'token': 1234567890` if token is a number. While it appears to work if you supply it as a string, because boto3 or DynamoDB is converting string to numeric, it's not a string (at least according to your original post).

Comment: yes, i guess it's a typo.. it should be `'token':1234567890` for a resource object.

Comment: What a nightmare, different syntaxes for different methods. Thanks Amazon. Thanks @HarshMath for figuring it out.