# dynamodb conditional update item (client)

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, botocore

I am referring to this sample of update item: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62030403/13967222.

```
    for key, val in body.items():
        update_expression.append(f" {key} = :{key},")
        update_values[f":{key}"] = val

    return "".join(update_expression)[:-1], update_values
```

I am trying to achieve the same but using dynamodb client.

Is there way I add check if the value is available using dynamodb client?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the key attribute already exists passing `ConditionExpression` parameter in the request like that (based on the response in the answer you're referring to):

```
table.update_item(
        Key={'uuid':str(uuid)},
        UpdateExpression=a,
        ExpressionAttributeValues=dict(v),
        ConditionExpression="attribute_not_exists(uuid)"
        )
```

Your write will be executed only when `ConditionExpression` returns `True`. `attribute_not_exists` is a DynamoDb function that returns `True` when the specified attribute does not exist. There is also a `attribute_exists` function to achieve the opposite result. More about DDB condition functions in [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Functions)

Also, you can check the Python example of conditional writes in [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.03.html#GettingStarted.Python.03.05)